# Could not launch Watch App

Tags: ios, deployment, watchkit, apple-watch

My Xcode version is 7.3.1 and Watch OS is 2.2.1 Deployment target set lower target also (Both are latest versions)

But, I couldn't launch the application. It alerts, "OS version lower than deployment target"

Answer (score 0):

Im using Xcode7.3.1 and got same problem first time running or real devices(iPhone&watch) and this should solve it :

Select Watch app -> go to build settings -> search for watchOS deployment Target ->select a lower version there based on the one you're using ,that the selected one by default is the highest version.
I believe that you need to repeat same steps for Watch kit extension app.